# Cassandra date insert from Java Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

To the type date in cassandra database I would like to insert a value. 
I tried with types java.util.Date and com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.
Both ways don't work for me.
For LocalDate error:

```
"JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (''); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4d549b00; line: 10, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.comarch.programs.dtos.ProgramDto[\"prgStartDate\"])",
```

Date error:

```
"Expected 4 byte long for date (8); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 byte long for date (8)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following way:

```
private Date accessDate;

@Transient
private Date activeDate;

public Date getActiveDate() {
    return activeDate;
}


public void setActiveDate(Date activeDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat sp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss+0000");
    String strDate = sp1.format(activeDate);
    try {
        this.activeDate = sp1.parse(strDate);
        setAccessDate(new java.sql.Timestamp(this.activeDate.getTime()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Use a transient data to format the date accordingly and set the date using java.sql.Timestamp